# Postgresql: create trigger to increment count_column between two tables?

Tags: postgresql

I have a table called `car` and another table called `inventory`.

`car` has a column called `needs_oil_change` (bool)

`inventory` has a column called `oil_change_due_count` INTEGER

I want to create a trigger that will incremented or decrement the `inventory.oil_change_due_count` whenever a `car.oil_change_due_count` is changed (or whenever a new car record is inserted, or deleted).

So, in short, I want a trigger to keep the inventory summary count column `oil_change_due_count` synchronized as car records are created/deleted/updated.

I've tried to follow some docs online like these:

https://w3resource.com/PostgreSQL/postgresql-triggers.php

https://dataegret.com/2017/10/postgresqls-transition-relations/

and others.

I haven't been able to create one that works yet.

How would I write a trigger that could handle that logic?

I just found this:

[PostgreSQL: Checking for NEW and OLD in a function for a trigger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50962700/postgresql-checking-for-new-and-old-in-a-function-for-a-trigger)

not sure if it will answer my question, but I will try to learn from that and see if I can apply to my question.

Comment: I think this is going to need the schema of the `car` and `inventory` tables.  Or at least more explanation on the relationship between `car.needs_oil_change`, `inventory.oil_change_due_count and `car.oil_change_due_count`.  In particular whether there is field in `inventory` that relates back to `car`?

Comment: car has an inventory_id FK. Inventory table does not have a car FK. So, car points to inventory. That’s how it’s laid out now.

Answer (score 2):

First of all you need to create a trigger function to handle the logic, in postgresql you can do something like this

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fn_oil_change() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
    BEGIN
        IF (TG_OP = 'DELETE') THEN
            UPDATE inventory SET oil_change_due_count = oil_change_due_count - OLD.oil_change_due_count;
            RETURN OLD;
        ELSIF (TG_OP = 'UPDATE') THEN
            ... some logic to hangle update 
            RETURN NEW
        ELSIF (TG_OP = 'INSERT') THEN
            ... some logic to hangle update
            RETURN NEW;
        END IF;
        RETURN NULL; -- result is ignored since this is an AFTER trigger
    END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

and then create the trigger itself

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER tg_oil_change
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE ON car
    FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE fn_oil_change();
```

Something more or less like this, right now I can't test the code, and you'll need to think how to handle the update.

Comment: yes, this looks great. I just wrote the trigger that handles updates and I tested it in data grip. Works great. Now I'll look at your example for the DELETE case.